# Server 2016 Updates failing to install

Tags: windows-update

2019-04 Cumulative Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4493473)
2018-09 Update for Windows Server 2016 for x64-based Systems (KB4091664)

Four failures to install on one particular server but have installed all of them on another 2016 box.
ESET File Security installed.
Server has been rebooted multiple times.
I've also tried purging the `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\DataStore` folder to no avail.

Is anyone else having these problems? I can't seem to find much info online.

Comment: Looking in the ReportingEvents.log file I keep seeing error 0x800F0922. Googling this gives me the following https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/install-update-error-0x800f0922/87a78355-1a84-4e0f-a0be-28f99a075e50

Comment: I've sorted the systemprofile problem. Sill KB4493473 refuses to install...

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest purging the `%windir%\SoftwareDistribution\Download\` folder as well. Sometimes there can be a bad or partial download in there that the update is trying to use.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I'll give this a go.

Comment: @RichM I don't have enough rep, otherwise I would respond up there... Anyways, looks like a lot of people did not have enough System Partition reserved space. Maybe that is your issue as well? Can you tell how much space yours has?

Comment: I have a single logical drive with 500MB System Reserved and the rest (278.87GB) as C:\ which has 202GB free space.

Comment: I see. As for the new problem, you should be able to go to ```C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\``` and create a file named 'Desktop'. You can also copy it from ```C:\users\default\desktop```. Link to this solution found [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/cwindowssystem32configsystemprofiledesktop-is/4faa2c49-c964-44c8-b38f-02432af8ee0e)

Comment: I've now run the Windows Update troubleshooter which has found "possible WU database errors" but has offered no way to fix. I've also run the `DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /RestoreHealth` command which has completed successfully but KB4493473 is still not downloading...

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling older updates?

Comment: No I haven't tried this, I'm a little wary of things screwing up completely if I do this.

Comment: Uninstalled ONE update: BSOD

Answer (score 0):

Following the disastrous removal of a single Windows Update, and the following disastrous attempt to recover, I've had to rebuild the server from scratch.
Luckily the rebuild has resulted in the Windows.old folder so I can recover information from there.